# Validate virtual class properties (Zend\Db\RowGateway)

Tags: symfony, symfony-validator

I want to use Symfony Validator Component for validating objects similar to Zend\Db\RowGateway. A very simplified example of this class looks like this:

```
class Task
{
    private $values;
    public function __construct(array $values)
    {
        $this->values = $values;
    }

    public function __get($name)
    {
        return $this->values[$name];
    }
}
```

validation.yml:

```
Task:
    properties:
        name:
            - NotBlank: ~
```

When validating an instance of Task I get the following error:
*Property name does not exist in class Row_Place*

Comment: Can you use @property by phpdoc

Comment: I think you could write a custom validator for this

Comment: @AndreasDyballa: How?

Comment: @Matteo: I don't think you can do that.

Comment: Did you try to set the constraint on getter (by replacing `properties` to `getters` on your `validation.yml` ?

Comment: @J-Mose: exception is the same, and I don't have getters

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate the underlying data in a collection (array) you can use the [Collection constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Collection.html). As Example, you can define a validation like:

```
Task:
    properties:
        value:
            - Collection:
                fields:
                    name:
                        - Required
                            - NotBlank: ~
```

Hope this help

Comment: The fact that Task stores it's values in a property is an implementation detail I don't want to care about when creating validators

Comment: Hi @NikoSams I understand  your needed but the Symfony Validator component [check for the properties](https://github.com/symfony/validator/blob/master/Mapping/PropertyMetadata.php#L41) with the php function `property_exists` that cannot detect properties that are magically accessible using the __get magic method. as described in the [doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php)

Comment: Yes, that's why I'm asking this. A custom Validator\MetadataFactory could probably do this, but I don't know how...

Comment: Sorry @NikoSams I post the code about HOW the validator component find the field you define for the constraint, so the engine can't find your component as well